# Is caching a table in a collection in a Windows Phone application bad practice?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, sql-server-ce, windows-phone

Here is my scenario

I have a SQLCE-table in Windows Phone app that contains a single column. In this column I have around 750 strings which I have to display to user in a Lisbox time to time.

In order to avoid querying the table again and again I have made a static collection of string. Now I only have to query table once because I store results of query in my static collection and rest of the times I am directly picking the list from static collection. It makes my UI more responsive.

If this would be a desktop app, I won't have bothered much but I am new to Windows Phone app and would like to know is it a bad practise? I am worried that 750 strings will be in memory of as long as my app is running. Is this a valid concern? If yes, any alternate?

Comment: I think it will stay in memory until you dispose it or your app closes if it is a static collection.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question maks no sense - circular.

> In order to avoid querying the table again and again I have made a static collection of string
>   and
>   If yes, any alternate?

lead to the immediate answer - yes, there is an alterantive. Query the database every time. is that an issue? Returning 750 strings is fast even on a mobile phone.

The rest can not be answered without more context.

> 750 strings which I have to display to user in a Lisbox time to time.

This can mean everything and nothing. What is "from time to time"? if it is some setup that gets used once every couple of hours, then obviously it is not smart to keep thosestrings around all the time just to not pull them from SQL Server. Is there a filter? showing 750 entries makes no sense on a desktop, it makes even a lot less on a small phone interface.

> It makes my UI more responsive

How? It saves 0.1 seconds once in a while? or 2 seconds every minute?

Without a lot more infromation that query is not answerable as the asnwer depends on usage patterns and the actual strings.

THAT SAID: I would doubt that the 750 row storage is necessary at all - just pull from database when you need them. And then do not wait until you ahve all of them to show the listbos - which is the next step: i doubt a 750 element listbox makes sense.

Comment: I have provided user a `textbox` on top of listbox for filtering. As user types, I filter the 750 strings. in the listbox. Yes, it save around 0.3 seconds. Enough time for user to notice

Comment: I can't say how much it will be used. It depends on the user.